# Generic Interface, of Generic Interface with Generics

Tags: c#, generics

Lot of Generics in my question, I hope it's still understandable...

I've the following Interfaces:

```
public interface ICommandBus
{
    TResult Publish<TCommand, TResult>(TCommand command)
        where TResult : ICommandResult
        where TCommand : ICommand<TResult>;
}

public interface ICommand<T>
    where T : ICommandResult
{ }

public interface ICommandResult
{
    bool Success { get; }
}
```

And i would like to use their implementations this way (I ommit the CommandBus, it's not usefull for this question, but you can find it [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/91693/commandbus-with-handlers-observers)):

```
public class CreateItemCommand: ICommand<CreateItemResult>
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
}
public class CreateItemResult: ICommandResult
{
    public bool Success { get; private set; }
}

var command = new CreateItemCommand();
var result = commandBus.Publish(command); //Error here
```

I've the error: `The type arguments cannot be inferred from the usage`.
I've tried something with [in](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/dd469484.aspx) and [out](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/dd469487.aspx) modifiers with no success...

How can I call my `Publish` method, wihout specifying the arguments type like this:

```
var result = commandBus.Publish<CreateItemCommand, CreateItemResult>(command); //Works, but ugly...
```

**EDIT: update for Lucas answer**

Lucas solution should work, but I still have to put the `where TResult : ICommandResult` constraint to avoid the error `There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'TResult' to 'Core.Command.ICommandResult'`.

I also have a huge problem with inheritance, let's say I have the following abstract CommandObserver:

```
public abstract class NotificationObserver<TResult> : ICommandObserver<TResult>
    where TResult : ICommandResult
{
    protected virtual bool IsEnable(ICommand<TResult> command, TResult result)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And it's implementation

```
public class CreateItemObserver : NotificationObserver<CreateItemResult>
{
    protected override bool IsEnable(CreateItemCommand command, CreateItemResult result)
    {
        return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(command.Name);
    }
}
```

This will not work, because the implementation doesn't really override the virtual method (not the same signature : `ICommand<TResult>` != `CreateItemCommand`).

And if I do keep the right signature, I can't use CreateItemCommand properties without an ugly cast in the implementation...

Comment: what's the point of all the generics? seems counter productive having both the generics and the specialization to some interface...

Comment: I think it's the point... I've abuse of Generics and now I'm stuck...

Comment: The follow-up question in the edit is a question of its own, so you should post it separately if you want it answered. You're trying to do a double dispatch here, maybe you should try the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a generics overdose here ;) Too many generics where simple inheritance would have given you easier results.

If you want to use your classes without refactoring entirely to get rid of the too many generics: you just need to specify the generic function call, because the compiler is just not intelligent enough to do this for you (resolving automatically a generic parameter is fine, resolving the generic parameter of a generic parameter is not).

```
var result = commandBus.Publish<CreateItemCommand, CreateItemResult>(command);
```

It's heavy, it's not particularly elegant, but at least it works. On a side note, your interface declaration itself is heavy, so it's not too surprising it's heavy to use too.

Comment: This is what I feared, as the code is quite complicated, the usage must be very explicit. I'm used to think of a bad smell when I see this kind of code, but I don't find any good refactoring here. If you think i can avoid all this complicated Generics, I'm very interessted by your idea !

Answer (score 4):

You can easily rewrite your interface like this to get rid of the `TCommand` parameter:

```
public interface ICommandBus
{
    TResult Publish<TResult>(ICommand<TResult> command)
        where TResult : ICommandResult;
}
```

Note that you can also remove `where TResult : ICommandResult`, since this constraint is redundant with the definition in `ICommand<TResult>`:

```
public interface ICommandBus
{
    TResult Publish<TResult>(ICommand<TResult> command);
}
```

I guess the reason why C# refuses to infer the type parameters in your case is that `TCommand` could implement `ICommand<T>` multiple times, like this:

```
public class SomeCommand : ICommand<Foo>, ICommand<Bar>
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: True, you can remove the `where TResult : ICommandResult` constraint, but I would keep it there. It's redundant, yes, but the constraint is there whatever you do, so having it explicitly written down makes the code easier to read and understand. Sometimes redundancy is good.

Comment: Can't remove this constraint because of `There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'TResult' to 'Core.Command.ICommandResult'`. This error appears on the `Publish` method. I think in this case, I should use `in` or `out` modifiers, but I don't understand them very well...

Comment: @jbuiss0n you can leave the constraint as-is, or if you know `TResult` is a class you could use the `class` constraint, or if you want to get rid of the constrains here, you could just write a double cast like this: `(TResult)(object)command` to bypass the error.

Comment: I prefer to avoid the double cast, I think it's a pain when you read and try to understand the code. I've also updated the question, because your solution works partially, because in my case I also have to manage inheritance...